# Haml, ruby on rails error: Encountered a syntax error while rendering template

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I tried to execute the following code but I got:

```
"Encountered a syntax error while rendering template:"
```

Here is my view:

```
%section
    %article
        - if @toss % 2 === 0
            %p the player #{@player_one.name} start the fight !
        - else 
            %p the player #{@player_two.name} start the fight !

        - while @hp_player_one > 0 && @hp_player_two > 0 
            - @hp_player_one -=  @player_two.attack
                %p  There is only #{@hp_player_one.to_s} point to #{@player_one.name}
            - @hp_player_two -=  @player_one.attack
                %p  There is only #{@hp_player_two.to_s} point to #{@player_two.name}
                -if @hp_player_one <= 0 && @hp_player_two > 0
                    %p #{@player_one.name} lost 
                -elsif @hp_player_two <= 0 && @hp_player_one > 0
                    %p #{@player_two.name} lost 
                -else 
                    %p draw !
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `%p draw ! ` looks suspect

Comment: also it looks like you have indented with tabs instead of double spaces.

Comment: @Kris yes, but what's wrong with the %p draw ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, I think you want something like this:

```
%section
    %article
        - if @toss % 2 === 0
            %p the player #{@player_one.name} start the fight !
        - else 
            %p the player #{@player_two.name} start the fight !

        - while @hp_player_one > 0 && @hp_player_two > 0 
            - @hp_player_one -=  @player_two.attack
            %p  There is only #{@hp_player_one.to_s} point to #{@player_one.name}
            - @hp_player_two -=  @player_one.attack
            %p  There is only #{@hp_player_two.to_s} point to #{@player_two.name}
            -if @hp_player_one <= 0 && @hp_player_two > 0
                %p #{@player_one.name} lost 
            -elsif @hp_player_two <= 0 && @hp_player_one > 0
                %p #{@player_two.name} lost 
            -else 
                %p draw !
```

In particular you shouldn’t indent after a line like

```
- @hp_player_one -=  @player_two.attack
```

as this doesn’t start a block. Haml sees the indentation after this line and assumes that it is the start of a block, and so inserts a corresponding `end` into the generated Ruby. These extra `end`s will give you `unexpected end, expecting end-of-input` syntax errors.